# Программное закрытие activity, открытой в виде диалога

Tags: java, android

Открываю activity в виде диалога, в котором есть recyclerview с записями из базы данных. При коротком клике на нужной записи, ее содержимое копируется в поля ввода другой activity. Мне нужно, чтобы после такого короткого клика, открытая в виде диалога activity автоматически закрывалась. Как это сделать?

```
            // Обработка коротких кликов:
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Получаем позицию (номер строки) на которой был сделан клик:
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
               <Какой-то код, выполняющий основную функцию>
            **ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ КОД ЗАКРЫТИЯ ACTIVITY**
        });
```

Comment: Может быть вам нужен `finish();`?

Comment: я пытался использовать finish(), но android studio не позволяет этого сделать. Если я пишу (в месте, где должен быть код закрытия): `acAddressBookDlg.finish();`
то studio выдает сообщение: "Non-static method finish() cannot be referenced from a static context".

Comment: тогда `dismiss()` можно попробовать

Comment: dismiss() используется для закрытия диалоговых окон, но не в случае, когда диалог - это activity. Во всяком случае, я пробовал его использовать, но android studio не позволяет делать это в связке с activity (activity.dismiss()). Тоже самое относится и к finishAffinity(). Правильного способа я не нашел.